# How do I Stop Import And Export Wizard in SQL Server 2017 when Not Responding after hitting <Stop>

Tags: sql-server, wizard

I once cancelled the wizard in SQLCMD but I don't remember how I did it. I've imported the Excel before so not sure why it hung up. I'm a beginner with no Admin experience. Thank you!

Comment: Did you make sure there is no dialog prompt hidden beneath a window or on another screen on your desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us whether you want to kill the Import and Export wizard via the Command Prompt when it is not responding. If so, please try to use the following command:

taskkill /f /im DTSWizard.exe